# trying to send an automatic email to the sender if the mailbox is hidden from exchange address list

Tags: email, exchange-2003

I have this situation:
When an employee finishes his work in my company, we archive his mailbox, back it up, we move his AD account to a "Disabled Users" OU and mark to hide his address from the exchange address list.
But if someone keeps sending this person an email, he doesn't receive any indication that the employee doesn't work here anymore.
Is there a way to let a sender know that he sent an email to a user which has left the company?
Something like the mailer daemon email which says undeliverable..
Thanks
Itai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better solution to this problem is to assign the SMTP address to the person taking over their responsibilities.

That way they can reply personally if its business related and update the sender of the change. When you remove the mailbox then remove the additional SMTP address. It does require a bit more tracking if you do it manually, but if you are repeating this often then you can script it.

Or if this is for outside contractors then create a generic Mailbox gone mailbox and set the ooa on it and then assign the smtp address to it when you disable the mailbox.

Comment: +1 - set a forward on the mailbox to another internal employee, then have that employee reply back if necessary with "John doesn't work here anymore, please use "x@y.com" for future emails.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you don't delete the mailbox? That'd do it.

**Edit**: OK, if you're not allowed to delete it immediately, then you could:

- Set an OOF message which tells the sender that this person has left, and/or
- Forward the mail to another mailbox. If you use an OOF you can mention this in that message as well.

If you do use both OOF and forwarding, be sure to deliver the mail to both the mailbox and the forwarding mailbox. If you only deliver to the forwarding mailbox, the OOF response isn't triggered.

Comment: We are not allowed to delete the mailbox for at least 6 months from the day the employee finished working in the company.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Exchange are you running? Here's something to get you started

1. Open EMC navigate to Recipient Configuration > Mailbox and highlight the account that you disabled
2. Right click on the disabled account and select Manage Full Access Permissions
3. Add your account to the list of the accounts that have full permissions
4. Now on your Workstation create a new outlook profile for the disabled account
5. Once Outlook opens navigate to Tools > Rules and Alerts
6. Click New Rule > Check messages when they arrive > Next > Yes to prompt > Have server reply using a specific message > click a specific message in Step 2  window  > Next > Next > Finish

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/477ee226-d7ab-4070-82cd-b595e4563c58

Comment: Yep, that doesn't even come close in 2003, but does work on newer versions.

Comment: Sigh, that's what I get for not reading tags. Sorry for the bad post =/