# I'd like to receive an indication when i send an email to a person which his account is disabled in AD

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to send an automatic email to the sender if the mailbox is hidden from exchange address list](https://serverfault.com/questions/366835/trying-to-send-an-automatic-email-to-the-sender-if-the-mailbox-is-hidden-from-ex)

When an employee leaves the company his exchange mailbox is being archived, backed up, his email address is marked to be hidden from exchange list, the user is set to disabled and moved to a "Disabled Users" OU.
After all this, if someone sends this person an email, he gets no indication that the employee is disabled or that he has left the company, so people keep sending him emails without knowing it will never reach this person.
Now my question is if there's a way to give the sender an indication that the user's mailbox is closed or something, i'm looking for a auto-reply message like when sending an email to an unknown email address (mailer daemon - mail could not be sent - or something like this).
I'm unable to delete the mailbox for at least one year after the employee finishes his work nor will I be able to enable out-of-the-office option.
Thanks
Itai